# Pandas count by time slots

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to pandas and it's still hard to understand how to do that. In pure python, it becomes so hard and unreadable. I need to count rows day-by-day with 1-hour time slots (is the begin-end range in this slot).

For ex., for data:

```
    begin_time              end_time
2020-01-01 11:02:10     2020-01-01 12:33:05
2020-01-01 12:22:20     2020-01-01 13:01:51
2020-01-02 09:02:24     2020-01-02 11:33:46
```

we'll have:

```
# for 2020-01-01
  time slot      count
11:00 - 12:00      1
12:00 - 13:00      2
13:00 - 14:00      1
...
```

Help will be gladly accepted. Thanks.

Comment: 2020-01-01 11:33:46 should probably be 2020-01-02 11:33:46

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question needs a bit more context but I think you're looking for

```
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='begin_time', freq='H')])['column_to_count'].count()
```

Comment: Thank you, almost what I'm looking for. I need to count all `x`s, where the intersection of `begin_time <= x < end_time` with the hourly time slots is not empty.